Electromagnetics: how to find armature value $K$?
A question has asked me for a steady state angular velocity at no load.
The formula I have is: $$V=e= K \ \phi \ \omega$$
To find $K$ (the armature value) the solutions have used $2/\pi$.
Another forum I saw has: $$\frac{z}{2 \pi} \ ,$$ where $z$ is number of conductors.
I cannot find a relevant equation on the formula sheet given, nor in my lectures.
I don’t know where the value $K= 2/\pi$ came from.
Can anyone explain please?

If you surround an equation with $, then it becomes like latex and so you can improve the formatting. \omega for omega, \phi for phi, as well as \frac{z}{2\pi} for the fraction later on.

You just solve for K from the open circuit voltage.
